# Cloudwatch Insight Query Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a problem, as I trying to automate the cloudwatch Logs insight query. I found this code

```
def getInsightLogCounts():
print("starting cloudwatch insight queries")
msg = ''
#STEP 1 - create a dict with query message as key and query as value. This can be stored in the db as well
query_Dict = getQueryDict()
log_group = '/the/loggroup/you/want/to/'
print("starting cloudwatch insight queries for " + str(log_group))
for x in query_Dict.items():
    query_key = x[0]
    query = x[1]
    print("query key : " + str(query_key) + " \n query : " + str(query))
#STEP 2 - Create a query response object using the start_query method of the logs. Here we are fetching data for the last 24 hours
start_query_response = logs_client.start_query(
        logGroupName=log_group,
        queryString=query,
        startTime=int((datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=24)).timestamp()),
        endTime=int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
        limit=1)
query_id = start_query_response['queryId']
    response = None
#STEP3 - run a while loop and waith for the query to complete.
while response == None or response['status'] == 'Running':
        time.sleep(1)
        response = logs_client.get_query_results(queryId=query_id)
#STEP4 - Extract the result and proceed to the next query
if response and response['results'] and response['results'][0] and response['results'][0][1]:
        #response found update msg
        msg = msg + str(query_key) + " : " + str(response['results'][0][1].get('value'))  + "; \n"
        print("query value returned for " + str(query_key) + " is : " + str(response['results'][0][1].get('value')))
    else:
        msg = msg + str(query_key) + " : 0"  + "; \n"
        print("no query data returned for " + str(query_key))
return msg
```

Now I need to fit my query into this code, but I'm new to the Lambda (Python) codes.

My query is (sample one)

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like 'END RequestId'
| sort @timestamp desc
```

If anyone has some ideas I would be very grateful if you can help me with this or just give me some advice

this is a link for the original post I took the code from.

https://medium.com/xebia-engineering/accessing-cloudwatch-metrics-and-insights-from-aws-lambda-1119c40ff80b#5833

Sorry guys, for the not clear post before. I manage to fit my code here so hopefully, someone with a big heart can help me

Comment: Hi! Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Sorry but I'm new here so I don't know the rules. I need a bit of help with this but when I try to paste all code the format looks very bad